# Speed up row addition with data.table

Tags: r, rows, data.table, subset

I read in a big dataset (10 000 * 25 000) with fread from `data.table` which happily goes super fast. Now I need to do some basic arithmetic with it which is, in comparison, quite slow. I wonder if anyone has a suggestion what I may do wrong / what would be a good tweak to get it faster (I have to do it 10 000 times, so every improvement counts!). I want to choose twice `ngeno` rows at random, add them up, and keep only the columns which are not all 0 (or 2), e.g. in

```
  mytable = matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 2,
                     0, 1, 2, 2), ncol=4))
```

columns 1 and 4 need to be deleted (resp. did not to be add up in the first place; usually aroung 40% of cols are deleted this way). What I have so far

```
# Test data
nrow = 1000
ncol = 10000
ngeno = 2000
require(data.table)
dat <- data.table(matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol, 2, 0.001), ncol=ncol))

# What I do
myway <- function(dat, nrow, ngeno) {
  set.seed(123)
  # Choose random rows
  haplo1 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  haplo2 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  # Add them up
  geno <- dat[haplo1,] + dat[haplo2,]
  rec.names <- names(dat)
  maf <- colMeans(geno)/2
  # throw out columns where every row has a 0 or a 2
  throw.out <- maf==0 | maf == 1
  rec.names <- rec.names[!throw.out]
  maf <- maf[!throw.out]
  geno <- subset(geno, select = rec.names)
  return(list(maf, geno))
}

myway2 <- function(dat, nrow, ngeno) {
  set.seed(123)
  haplo1 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  haplo2 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  dat <- data.table(t(dat))
  geno <- dat[,haplo1,with=F] + dat[,haplo2,with=F]
  geno <- data.table(t(geno))
  maf <- colMeans(geno)/2
  throw.out <- maf==0 | maf == 1
  maf <- maf[!throw.out]
  geno <- geno[, which(!throw.out), with=F]
  return(list(maf, geno))
}

eddisway <- function(dat, nrow, ngeno) {
  set.seed(123)
  dat.m <- as.matrix(dat)
  haplo1 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  haplo2 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  geno <- dat.m[haplo1,] + dat.m[haplo2,]
  maf <- colMeans(geno)/2
  throw.out <- maf==0 | maf == 1
  maf <- maf[!throw.out]
  geno <- geno[,!throw.out]
  return(list(maf, geno))
}

require(reshape2)
rolandsway <- function(dat, nrow, ngeno) {
  set.seed(123)
  dat1 <- melt(dat, variable.factor=FALSE)
  
  # Choose random rows
  haplo1 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  haplo2 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  
  geno <- dat1[, value[haplo1]+value[haplo2], by=variable]
  maf <- geno[, mean(V1)/2, by=variable]  
  
  maf <- maf[!(V1==0 | V1==1),]
  setkey(geno, variable)
  geno <- geno[maf[, variable],]
#   geno[,"v2":=rep(1:dim(dat)[1],dim(maf)[1]),with=F]
#   test <- dcast.data.table(geno, v2 ~ variable)
  return(list(maf, geno))
}

# Warning messages from Roland's method:
#   1: In melt.data.table(dat, variable.factor = FALSE) :
#   To be consistent with reshape2's melt, id.vars and measure.vars are internally guessed when both are 'NULL'. All non-numeric/integer/logical type columns are conisdered id.vars, which in this case are columns ''. Consider providing at least one of 'id' or 'measure' vars in future.

require(microbenchmark)
out <- microbenchmark(myway(dat, nrow, ngeno), myway2(dat, nrow, ngeno), eddisway(dat, nrow, ngeno), rolandsway(dat, nrow, ngeno), times=5)
```

Result so far:

```
# Unit: seconds
#                               expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# myway(dat, nrow, ngeno)      3.764377 3.804865 3.841819 3.924095 4.203679    10
# myway2(dat, nrow, ngeno)     3.595477 3.681658 3.703837 3.784004 3.851407    10
# eddisway(dat, nrow, ngeno)   1.388514 1.414389 1.438111 1.479081 1.574927    10
# rolandsway(dat, nrow, ngeno) 2.253587 2.299850 2.390655 2.579183 2.633778    10
```

Profiling `myway` gets me something like

```
$by.self
                        self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"[["                         0.94     18.8       2.56      51.2
"[[.data.frame"              0.54     10.8       1.62      32.4
"match"                      0.48      9.6       0.92      18.4
"[.data.table"               0.40      8.0       2.84      56.8
"Ops.data.frame"             0.34      6.8       1.44      28.8
"setattr"                    0.24      4.8       2.18      43.6
"<Anonymous>"                0.18      3.6       0.46       9.2

$by.total
                           total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"myway"                          5.00     100.0      0.00      0.0
"[.data.table"                   2.84      56.8      0.40      8.0
"["                              2.84      56.8      0.00      0.0
"[["                             2.56      51.2      0.94     18.8
"alloc.col"                      2.26      45.2      0.06      1.2
"setattr"                        2.18      43.6      0.24      4.8
"+"                              1.96      39.2      0.00      0.0
```

As "+" is only the 7th from the top (and the line with the addition takes most of the time), I thought there would be room for improvement. I tried using `subset` by transforming haplo1 and haplo2 into booleans, but this even took longer. Also compiling didn't help. Any suggestions how to make it quicker or is this already the end of the line?

### Update:

I updated the functions (plus, I fixed a typo). I wasn't able until now to get the same output format with Roland's method. But even without it, Eddi's suggestion seems to be faster. Any other ideas?

Comment: the way you're using your data you'll only get slowed down by `data.table` and should instead use matrices (that's not to say that there isn't a better way of doing it - I'm just commenting on existing code)

Comment: Thanks for the good hint! I implemented your suggestion and until now, it is the fastest. I wouldn't have thought that using data.table naïvely slows me done that much.

Answer (score 1):

`melt`ing to long format achieves a speed-up by a factor of 2, but changes also the output format:

```
myway1 <- function(dat, nrow, ngeno) {

  dat1 <- melt(dat, variable.factor=FALSE)

  # Choose random rows
  haplo1 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)
  haplo2 <- sample.int(nrow, ngeno, replace=T)

  geno <- dat1[, value[haplo1]+value[haplo2], by=variable]
  maf <- geno[, mean(V1)/2, by=variable]  

  maf <- maf[!(V1==0 | V1==1),]
  setkey(dat1, variable)
  geno <- dat1[maf[, variable],]
  return(list(maf, geno))
}
```

Further improvements should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would need the same output format as in `myway`. Not necessarily a data.table, but also wide-format. I tried to get it using `dcast.data.table`, but failed so far (I also fixed a type of mine; I want to return a subset of `geno`, not of `dat`). Interestingly, Eddi's method seems even faster, without any data.table method.